# TensorFlow Object Detection API Weird Behavior

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, classification, object-detection

I was playing with TensorFlow's brand new [Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) and decided to train it on some other publicly available datasets.

I happened to stumble upon [this](https://github.com/gulvarol/grocerydataset) grocery dataset which consists of images of various brands of cigarette boxes on the supermarket shelf along with a text file which lists out the bounding boxes of each cigarette box in each image. 10 major brands have been labeled in the dataset and all other brands fall into the 11th "miscellaneous" category.

I followed their [tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_pets.md) and managed to train the model on this dataset. Due to limitations on processing power, I used only a third of the dataset and performed a 70:30 split for training and testing data. I used the faster_rcnn_resnet101 model. All parameters in my config file are the same as the default parameters provided by TF.

After 16491 global steps, I tested the model on some images but I am not too happy with the results -

[image]
Failed to detect the Camels in top-shelf whereas it detects the product in other images

[image]
Why does it fail to detect the Marlboros in the top row?

[image]
Another issue I had is that the model never detected any other label except for label 1

[image]

Doesn't detected a crop instance of the product from the training data

[image]

It detects cigarette boxes with 99% confidence even in negative images!

Can somebody help me with what is going wrong? What can I do to improve the accuracy? And why does it detect all products to belong in category 1 even though I have mentioned that there are 11 classes in total?

**Edit** Added my label map:

```
item {
  id: 1
  name: '1'
}

item {
  id: 2
  name: '2'
}

item {
  id: 3
  name: '3'
}

item {
  id: 4
  name: '4'
}

item {
  id: 5
  name: '5'
}

item {
  id: 6
  name: '6'
}

item {
  id: 7
  name: '7'
}

item {
  id: 8
  name: '8'
}

item {
  id: 9
  name: '9'
}

item {
  id: 10
  name: '10'
}

item {
  id: 11
  name: '11'
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the label map for your job?

Comment: @JonathanHuang I added my label map in the edit

Comment: Thanks, that looks just fine.  It may be the case, as others have mentioned, that you need more data, but I'm pretty mystified why you'd always predict the same class... perhaps you need to double check the TFRecord files again?

Comment: i notice that the labels are limitted to 20 somehow..

Comment: @BanachTarski good work. May you share your code of creating tfrecords from the grocery dataset?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So I think I figured out what is going on. I did some analysis on the dataset and found out that it is skewed towards objects of category 1.

This is the frequency distribution of the each category from 1 to 11 (in 0 based indexing)

```
0 10440
1 304
2 998
3 67
4 412
5 114
6 190
7 311
8 195
9 78
10 75
```

I guess the model is hitting a local minima where just labelling everything as category 1 is good enough.

About the problem of not detecting some boxes : I tried training again, but this time I didn't differentiate between brands. Instead, I tried to teach the model what a cigarette box is. It still wasn't detecting all the boxes.

Then I decided to crop the input image and provide that as an input. Just to see if the results improve and it did!

It turns out that the dimensions of the input image were much larger than the 600 x 1024 that is accepted by the model. So, it was scaling down these images to 600 x 1024 which meant that the cigarette boxes were losing their details :)

So, I decided to test the original model which was trained on all classes on cropped images and it works like a charm :)

[image: Original image]

This was the output of the model on the original image

[image: Top left corner cropped from original image]

This is the output of the model when I crop out the top left quarter and provide it as input.

Thanks everyone who helped! And congrats to the TensorFlow team for an amazing job for the API :) Now everybody can train object detection models!

Comment: Hi @Banach Tarski, you mentioned that you scaled down the images. How do you deal with the change of annotation?

Comment: The annotations should be taken in relative to the size of the image and not absolute co-ordinates. That way the annotations are invariant to scaling.

Comment: Thank you very much! Did you quantify the improvement of mAP after scaling down the training images?

Comment: Actually I scaled down the images during inference because the images in my test set were significantly larger than what I trained my model on :) But yes, in theory you can use this technique as a data augmentation mechanism for sparse training data sets where the image sizes are very large,

Comment: I have same issue. I trained the model with 3 classes after 49000 steps with 1 batch size the model predicted 1 class for all objects but the objects are detected perfectly just the wrong label. Later i tried early stopping but found the model returns randomly out of 3 classes. I tried this with some tutorial dataset and it seems to predict more than two classes in early stopping. Should i re annotate by dataset or do you have any suggestion ?

Answer (score 5):

How many images are there in the dataset? The more training data that you have the better the API performs. I tried training it on about 20 images per class, the accuracy was pretty bad. I pretty much faced all the problems that you have mentioned above. When I generated more data, the accuracy improved considerably.

PS: Sorry I couldn't comment since I don't have enough reputation

Comment: There are 300 images in the dataset, each image contains multiple instances of each of the classes. I estimate that for each brand there are more than 1000 instances of that brand in the 300 images. Also, was the class labelling in your model correct?

Comment: The class labelling was very similar to the one that you have posted. Even my model started predicting everything with high confidence. I believe it learnt the very basic features from the limited amount of data that I provided.

Comment: Hmm.. so is the issue just that there is not enough data or that I did not train it enough? Damn, that just seems silly. I will run the model for more iterations and see if anything improves

Comment: I don't think that will be of much help, because after a point the training converges. Since you've already run 16000 steps, running more iterations will be redundant. I would suggest that you try and increase the data. Also could you re-check  your annotations in case you missed/mis-labelled some of the data.

Comment: Yeah I increased the data as well. Initially I had used just a third of the data for training. Will try the full dataset and more iterations and see if things improve.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is too late now, but I wanted to post the comments if anyone struggles with this in the future:

Unfortunately, TF documentation is not the best and I struggled with this a lot before finding the reason. The way the model is constructed is that it allows for a MAXIMUM of x amount of predictions per single image. In your case I think it is 20. You can easily test my hypothesis by editing the original photo like this: [image]

Obviously before the boxes are actually drawn and you should see some better results.

Pretty nasty limitation.

Answer (score 2):

There are some parameters to configure like:

```
train_input_reader {
  max_number_of_boxes: 1000
}

eval_input_reader {
  max_number_of_boxes: 1000
}
```

They are very important. By default they are set to 100.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, the dataset size is rather small. Resnet is a large network, which will require even more data to train properly.

What to do:

1. Increase data set size
2. Use pre-trained networks and fine tune on your dataset (you probably already do this)
3. Use data augmentation (resize, blur,...; flipping may not be appropriate for this dataset).

Comment: I can try to do that but I don't understand why it labels objects with 99% confidence after ~16000 global steps. Shouldn't it have learned at least something by now to distinguish between brands?