# when resize images in tensorflow object detection api, which function realize the resize of box coordinates?

Tags: tensorflow

When I check the code, if I set a `image_resizer` in the `.config` file, I found the image will be resized in the function SSDMetaArch.preprocess(), but I cannot find which function is used to resize corresponding groundtruth bbox coordinates.

Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: This post was maybe what you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45137835/what-the-impact-of-different-dimension-of-image-resizer-when-using-default-confi