# Tensorflow Object Detection Limit

Tags: object, tensorflow, limit, detection

Following the code here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb

No matter the image inputted, there seems to be a hard limit of 20 objects detected. Example:[image]

The problem is also seen in this post: [TensorFlow Object Detection API Weird Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45029977/tensorflow-object-detection-api-weird-behavior)

Is there some configuration or parameter that can be changed to raise the number of objects detected?

**EDIT**: I can confirm that greater than 20 objects are detected, but there is a maximum of 20 that will be shown in the final output. Is there a way to increase this limit?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The max number of detections can be set in your config file. By default it's usually 300, so you should be fine.

Your problem here is the number of *displayed* detections. Towards the end of your code you have a call to [`vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py). Just add `max_boxes_to_draw=None` to its arguments to display all the detections (or choose some bigger number if you want).