# tensorflow object detection api and bboxes by image frame

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning, object-detection

Reading questions\answers of other people by tag [python] I faced an amazing work by Banach Tarski [TensorFlow Object Detection API Weird Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45029977/tensorflow-object-detection-api-weird-behavior) . So, I wanted to retry out what he did to more deeply understand  [Tensorflow Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection). I followed step by step what he did as well as I was using [Grocery Dataset](https://github.com/gulvarol/grocerydataset). The faster_rcnn_resnet101 model was taken with default parameters and batch_size = 1.

The real difference was that I took not Shelf_Images with annotations and bbs for each class on them but Product_Images where there were 10 folders (for each for one class) and in each folder you could see full size images of cigarettes without any background. Avg size of Product_Images is 600*1200 whilst Shelf_Images is 3900*2100. So, I thought why I just can't take these full images and take bounding boxes out of them, then train on it and get successful result. By the way I didn't need to manually crop images as Banach Tarski did because of 600*1200 is so great fit for faster_rcnn_resnet101 neural network model and its default parameters of input images.

**Example one of the images out of class Pall Mall**

[image]

It seemed simple because I could create bboxes just by image's contours. So, I just needed to create annotations for each image and create tf_records out of them for training. 
I took the formula for creating bboxes by image contours

```
x_min = str(1)
y_min = str(1)
x_max = str(img.width - 10)
y_max = str(img.height - 10)
```

**Example of xml annotation**

```
<annotation>
    <folder>VOC2007</folder>
    <filename>B1_N1.jpg</filename>
    <path>/.../grocery-detection/data/images/1/B1_N1.jpg</path>
    <source>
        <database>The VOC2007 Database</database>
        <annotation>PASCAL VOC2007</annotation>
        <image>flickr</image>
        <flickrid>192073981</flickrid>
    </source>
    <owner>
        <flickrid>tobeng</flickrid>
        <name>?</name>
    </owner>
    <size>
        <width>811</width>
        <height>1274</height>
        <depth>3</depth>
    </size>
    <segmented>0</segmented>
    <object>
        <name>1</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>1</xmin>
            <ymin>1</ymin>
            <xmax>801</xmax>
            <ymax>1264</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

After script iterating over all folder images I've got for each image annotation similar what I showed above in VOC2007 xml type. Then I created tf_records iterating over each annotation, taking it as it was in   [pet_running](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_pets.md) example done by tensorflow and all seemed great now and ready for training on AWS Nvidia Tesla k80

**Example of feature_dict that is used for creating Tf_records**

```
feature_dict = {
      'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(height),
      'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(width),
      'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(
          data['filename'].encode('utf8')),
      'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(
          data['filename'].encode('utf8')),
      'image/key/sha256': dataset_util.bytes_feature(key.encode('utf8')),
      'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_jpg),
      'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature('jpeg'.encode('utf8')),
      'image/object/bbox/xmin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmins),
      'image/object/bbox/xmax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmaxs),
      'image/object/bbox/ymin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymins),
      'image/object/bbox/ymax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymaxs),
      'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text),
      'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
      'image/object/difficult': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(difficult_obj),
      'image/object/truncated': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(truncated),
      'image/object/view': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(poses),
}
```

After 12458 steps by 1 image per step the model converged to a local minima. I saved all checkpoints and graph. Next I created out of it inference graph and run object_detection_tutorial.py to show how it all works on my test images. But I'm not happy with the result at all. 
P.S the last one image has 1024 × 760 size and also cropped as top part of 3rd image that has 3264 × 2448. So I tried different size images of cigarettes to accidantly not to lose image details during image scaling by model.

**Output: classified images with predicted bboxes**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is, that your network learned that objects have nearly the same size than the input images, because every training image contains only one positive object with nearly the same size as the input image itself.

I think your dataset would be a good starting point for a cigarette package classifier, but not for a object detector.

The Faster-R-CNN model needs samples with objects, but also background. The model will then find objects in the images in a two stepped approach. In the first step a so called Region proposal network will look for interesting areas in the image. These interesting areas will then be classified in a second step. With this second step the model decides if an area is actual an object or only background.

So to train a cigarette object detector you need a lot samples like the last picture of your post, where all objects (cigarette packages) are labeled with a separate BBOX and class label.

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks for the advice. Hope this will help someone else as well/